# How To Overlay Full Body Of Web Page With a Solid Image (on top)

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I want to cover up the entire body area (arbitrary body) with an image file stretched to cover it. I've tried using background but even with z-index that does not seem to so it.

I've tried below but that just pushes the real web page down.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
          <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <title></title>
            <style>
              .box {
                width: 100%;
                height: 100%;
                z-index: 999;
                background-size: 1%;
                background-repeat: repeat;
              }
            </style>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div>
              <img src="solid-white.png" class="box" />
              <div>ajldfskaf</div>
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Pick your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this CSS (no extra element necessary):

```
body { position: relative; }
body::before {
  content: "";
  background-image: url(path/to/your/solid-white.png);
  background-size: cover;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}
```

Comment: Btw, if you only want a fully opaque white cover, just use `background-color: #fff;` instead of a useless image.

Comment: I'm creating a chrome extension that overlays the current page with NASA's image of the day (not a white background).  The only odd thing I'm finding is that if the body is short, then the picture gets cut off going down. Not sure if it's possible, but what I really want is everything on the page turned off, then I fade in the picture at the current browser width. I want it to go down as far as it can, but what's happening is it cuts off at where the body would have gone.

Comment: @Pete You could screenshot that and ask a new question on that, along with the code you have so far (not as an image!).

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```js
let newDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
newDiv.setAttribute("id", "hide");
document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
document.getElementById("hide").style.zIndex = "9";
document.getElementById("hide").style.width = "100%";
document.getElementById("hide").style.height = "100%";
document.getElementById("hide").style.backgroundImage = "url('https://s3.amazonaws.com/cdn-origin-etr.akc.org/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/22224952/beagle-puppy-in-large-cushion-chair.jpg')";
document.getElementById("hide").style.backgroundRepeat = "no-repeat";
document.getElementById("hide").style.backgroundSize = "cover";
document.getElementById("hide").style.top = "0";
document.getElementById("hide").style.position = "fixed";
document.body.style.margin = "0";
document.body.style.padding = "0";
```

Comment: Why do `document.getElementById("hide").style.zIndex = "9";` instead of `newDiv.style.zIndex = "9";`?

Comment: @connexo newDiv is declared to create the `<div>`, to avoid interpretation issues on the code, I used it to declare in a variable and after, put the styles and elements using the div's ID for clearer view as it'd be easier to not mess up with variables later (supposing that this can be used to more events and to so, having more divs to be created in the code).